# My child process doesn't automatically exit after finishing work in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process, console.log

I use `cluster\child_process.fork` create multiple child processes, then I found that when I `console.log` a lot of content in the child process, my child process cannot exit automatically, the same code exits normally when I reduce the output content.

Here is the minimal reproducible code:

```js
const child_process = require('child_process');
const stream = require('stream');

class _Transform extends stream.Transform {
  _transform(chunk, encode, next) {
    next(null, chunk);
  }
}

if (!('IS_WORKER' in process.env)) {
  const worker = child_process.fork(process.argv[1], process.argv.slice(2), {
    silent: true,
    env: {
      IS_WORKER: 1,
    },
  });
  const cache = new _Transform();
  worker.stdout.pipe(cache);
  console.log('master start');
  worker.on('message', e => {
    console.log(e);
  });
  worker.on('exit', (code, signal) => {
    console.log(code, signal);
    cache.pipe(process.stdout);
  });
} else {
  process.send('hello from child');
  console.log(new Array(100000).fill(1).join('')); // It is normal to set a smaller number
  process.removeAllListeners();
  process.channel.unref();
}
```

how can I solve this

In fact, I want to collect the console.log content of all subprocesses in the main process and output them at once.